# Error thrown citing match arms with incompatible types when pattern matching an Option

Tags: hashmap, rust, pattern-matching, option-type

I am fairly new to Rust and cannot get my head around this confusing error.

I am simply trying to match on an `Option` returned by the `get` function of a `HashMap`. If a value is returned I want to increment it, if not I want to add a new element to the map.

Here is the code:

```
let mut map = HashMap::new();
map.insert("a", 0);
let a = "a";
match map.get(&a) {
    Some(count) => *count += 1,
    None => map.insert(a, 0),
}
```

The resulting error:

```
error[E0308]: match arms have incompatible types
  --> <anon>:7:5
   |
7  |       match map.get(&a) {
   |  _____^ starting here...
8  | |         Some(count) => *count += 1,
9  | |         None => map.insert(a, 0),
10 | |     }
   | |_____^ ...ending here: expected (), found enum `std::option::Option`
   |
   = note: expected type `()`
              found type `std::option::Option<{integer}>`
note: match arm with an incompatible type
  --> <anon>:9:17
   |
9  |         None => map.insert(a, 0),
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I am not really sure what types the compiler is complaining about here, as both `Some` and `None` are both part of the same enum type. Can anyone explain what issue the compiler is having with my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is referring to the value the match arm bodies return, not the type of the pattern of each match arm.

```
Some(count) => *count += 1,
None => map.insert(a, 0),
```

The expression `*count += 1` evaluates to `()` (called "unit" in Rust, "void" in many other languages). The expression `map.insert(a, 0)` on the other hand returns `Option<V>` where `V` is the value type of the hash map (an integer in your case). Suddenly the error message does make some sense:

```
= note: expected type `()`
= note:    found type `std::option::Option<{integer}>`
```

I suppose you don't even want to return something from the `match` block (remember: `match` blocks are expressions, too, so you could return something from it). To discard the result of any expression, you can convert it to a statement with `;`. Let's try this:

```
match map.get(&a) {
    Some(count) => {
        *count += 1;
    }
    None => {
        map.insert(a, 0);
    }
}
```

Each match arm body is a block now (something between `{` and `}`) and each block contains one statement. Note that we technically don't need to change the first match arm, as `*count += 1` already returns `()`, but this way it's more consistent.

---

But once you test this, another error related to borrowing will be shown. This is a well known issue and is explained in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30851464/want-to-add-to-hashmap-using-pattern-match-get-borrow-mutable-more-than-once-at). In short: the borrow checker is not smart enough to recognize that your code is fine and therefore you should use the super nice [`entry`-API](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry):

```
let map = HashMap::new();
map.insert("a", 0);
let a = "a";
*map.entry(&a).or_insert(0) += 1;
```

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly!

I will look a bit more into the `entry` API it looks very useful.